# Podfile.lock not updating after pod update

Tags: cocoapods

I'm trying to update a pod version. Following along with [pod install vs. pod update](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html) Here are the steps I followed:

1. `$ pod outdated`

```
The following pod updates are available:
- LibraryA 3.2.0 -> 3.2.0 (latest version 7.1.0)
- LibraryB 3.0.0 -> 3.0.0 (latest version 3.1.0)
```

2. `$ pod update LibraryA`

```
Pod installation complete!
```

```
// Podfile.lock
- LibraryA (3.2.0) # no change
```

3. `$ pod outdated`

```
The following pod updates are available:
- LibraryA 3.2.0 -> 3.2.0 (latest version 7.1.0)
- LibraryB 3.0.0 -> 3.0.0 (latest version 3.1.0)
```

So far, no change to Podfile.lock, and the version is still outdated.

4. `$ rm Podfile.lock`
5. `$ pod install`
6. `$ pod outdated`

```
The following pod updates are available:
- LibraryA 3.2.0 -> 3.2.0 (latest version 7.1.0)
- LibraryB 3.0.0 -> 3.0.0 (latest version 3.1.0)
```

Still, no change. What's the appropriate procedure here to update to the latest version of a pod?

Comment: I have the same problem.  I know it isn't a solution but I wanted to highlight a possible workaround, which is to delete Podfile.lock and run `pod install` to recreate the lock file from scratch.  Watch out for unexpected changes to other pods though.